# How to sort array elements in lexicographic order in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have an array

```
arr = [[1,2],[2,3],[2,1],[0,1]]
```

I would like them to be in order:

```
arr = [[0,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,3]]
```

I would like to use Ruby's `sort_by` method to do this. How could I sort an array of arrays on two levels in Ruby like this?

Comment: I have a hard time calling this "lexicographic" since you don't say what should happen if there's a 10. This appears to be numeric, first by element 0, then by element 1.

Comment: @DaveNewton It's the exact same logic than lexicographic sort : compare the first elements. If they're equal, compare the second one, and so on...

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes, depending on how it's implemented.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Comparing element-by-element is the *definition* of lexicographic ordering.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Lexicographic sorting means comparing by alphabetic representation.

Comment: @DaveNewton nope. Lexicographic ordering is derived from the way words are sorted but it doesn't require any string.

Comment: @EricDuminil I have yet to find a definition apart from Wolfram that supports this, and certainly in *common* usage, it refers to strings. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order but Wolfram's definition doesn't specify strings, so I'll defer to that. Mea culpa.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Thanks for the comment. Everything that comes after https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Cartesian_products in your link is a generalisation of lexicographical order, without any string involved.

Comment: @EricDuminil Yup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Array#sort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) sorts sub-arrays lexicographically by default (see [`Array#<=>`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)). You don't need to define anything:

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[2,1],[0,1]].sort
# => [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 3]]
```

If you really want to use `sort_by`:

```
[[1,2],[2,3],[2,1],[0,1]].sort_by(&:itself)
# => [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you consider each element of the subarray to be a digit from 0 to 9, you could use [`Array#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), where the block converts the array into string then into integer:

```
arr.sort_by { |e| e.join.to_i }

#=> [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 3]]
```

---

How it works.

```
[1, 2].join #=> "12"
[1, 2].join.to_i #=> 12
```

---

In this case:

```
arr = [[1,0,2,0],[2,3],[2,1],[0,1]]
#=> [[0, 1], [2, 1], [2, 3], [1, 0, 2, 0]]
```

Comment: Or when each element is a single digit.

Comment: Why don't you just use `Array#sort`? Since `Array#<=>` already *is* lexicographic, you don't need to do anything at all, and will work for arbitrarily sized sub-arrays with arbitrary contents. Your method will not work when the sub-arrays are of different size, and will not work if the contents are not digits.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes, too easy to be true: I felt like the OP already tested on some different sets of data and found a problem..

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, of course: my interpretation of OP question is that each element is a digit from 0 to 9.

Comment: If the digits could be any length, what changes?

Comment: @Maggie, what do you mean? Digits are the building blocks to form numbers. I interpreted your question in a wrong way maybe. If Eric's answer is correct for you, you should accept it. Or improve your question to let other help.